# How to handle unique constraint exception in datatable while adding record in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added unique constraint to datatable like this

```
DataTable dtemp
private void TempTable() 
{
 dtemp = new DataTable("Temp");
 dtemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Table", typeof(int)));
 dtemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Capacity", typeof(int)));
 UniqueConstraint TableUnique = new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { dtemp.Columns["Table"] });
 dtemp.Constraints.Add(TableUnique);
}
```

When I try to add same record, instead of going to catch block, it simply exit the program abruptly and gives unique constraint unhandled exception in the visual studio.

```
private void GetTable()
    {
        try
        { 
            dtemp.Rows.Add(mTable.TableID,mTable.Capacity);
        }
        catch(SqlException ee)
        {
            if (ee.Number == 2627)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, This Table Is Already Reserved!");
                if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { Con.Close(); }
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ee.Message);
        }
```

Can anyone please tell me how to handle this exception?

Comment: I would avoid using exceptions in this scenario.  This is really a bad pattern.  It is especially painful to debug when you have all exceptions turned on.  A better practice is to check if the record exists, then add if it doesn't.

Comment: Another question - why are you using a data table for this? It looks like a Dictionary<> would suit your needs and would be much faster.  Dictionary<int, int>().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have define your constraint in the local `DataTable`, you're trying to catch the wrong type of exception. Instead of `SqlException`, a [`ConstraintException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.constraintexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is thrown.

An immediate fix would be, to change the type of exception in your `try` clause:

```
try
{ 
    dtemp.Rows.Add(mTable.TableID,mTable.Capacity); 
} 
catch (ConstraintException ee) 
{
    // handle the exception here 
}
```

If you want to check your constraint in the database, then that's where you want to define it instead of in the `DataTable`. In this case, `SqlException` will get thrown, but only when you send the data to the database, not when you add a row to the `DataTable`.

Comment: I would avoid using exceptions in this scenario.  This is really a bad pattern.  It is especially painful to debug when you have all exceptions turned on.  A better practice is to check if the record exists, then add if it doesn't.

Comment: tsells can you please share the code to check if the record exists or not before adding

Comment: @RohithJNayak Check [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx) for finding a row in `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a SQLException.  Change your handling to be more specific around the exception.  If you can't resolve that - change it to a regular Exception.

```
private void GetTable()
    {
        try
        { 
            dtemp.Rows.Add(mTable.TableID,mTable.Capacity);
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ee.Message);
        }
```

I would avoid using exceptions in this scenario.  This is really a bad pattern.  It is especially painful to debug when you have all exceptions turned on.  A better practice is to check if the record exists, then add if it doesn't.

Think of exceptions as edge cases for unexpected events - not regular coding practices.

Comment: Try [ConstraintException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yfsd47w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank You Damir for the answer. Can please tell me the exception code like 2627 of above to handle this exception manually